# Weird behavior with SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to refresh a div with JavaScript every 20 seconds. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    refreshTable();
    updateTable();
});

function updateTable(){
    setTimeout( refreshTable, 20000);
    updateTable();
}

function refreshTable(){
    $('#table_list').load('table')
}
```

Once the page is ready, I can start my countdown. But this code is updating the table every 3 seconds. Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

P.s.: I saw that is a common issue here, but any of the questions that I saw were able to help me.

Comment: The `updateTable()` call should be inside the `setTimeout` callback, not after it.

Comment: @Viet The code is perfectly sufficient, but the mistake is too obvious and there’s no debugging attempt.

Comment: You're right. My bad.

Comment: @Xufox, I'm a newbie in JS. is there an IDE or something to debug? is Chrome an option?

Comment: You can use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and `console.log`, but in this case, you should just [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code. It’s short enough.

Comment: Is there a way to call only once? Everytime that `$('#table_list').load('table')` is called JS is creating a new thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the document is ready, you call `updateTable`.

After 20 seconds, it calls `refreshTable` but it **immediately** calls `updateTable` again. So it queues up another `refreshTable` and then hits `updateTable` **again**. This sticks it into an infinite loop … or at least into stack overflow.

You need to either:

- Call `updateTable` from inside `refreshTable` instead of `updateTable`
- Use `setInterval` in the `ready` handler instead of using `setTimeout` at all

Answer (score 2):

You have infinite recursion:

```
function updateTable(){
    setTimeout( refreshTable, 20000);
    updateTable(); // Infinite recursion.
}
```

You should use setIinterval instead of making your setTimeout loop.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers are pointing out, you have infinite recursion in your updateTable function. You could instead use setInterval, which periodically runs the specified refreshTable function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  refreshTable();
  setInterval(refreshTable, 2000)
});

function refreshTable(){
  $('#table_list').load('table')
}
```

Comment: Yes, setInterval is a much safer way to call something repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setInterval( function(){
        $('#table_list').load('table');
    }, 20000);
});
```

This might help you out, at least i hope so :D

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the "complete" callback of the jQuery method ".load()"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('#table_list').load('table', function(){
        setTimeout( refreshTable, 20000);
    });
}
```

Thus, setTimeout will be executed after query processing and HTML insertion has been performed. Please notice that we don't need the "updateTable" auxiliary function anymore as we now call the "refreshTable" function recursively.